# File_get_content not working throws an error

Tags: php

Im quite new to PHP, i used the file_get_contents syntax, but it returns an error saying

```
Warning: file_get_contents(url: http://localhost/setc.php?userid=123&amp;panelid=1): failed to open stream: No error in
```

this is the code that i using

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('url: '.Config_Reader::readConfig('localhome')->base_url.'setc.php?userid=123&panelid=1');
echo $homepage;
```

can anybody help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("'".Config_Reader::readConfig('localhome')->base_url."setc.php?userid=123&panelid=1'");
```

Comment: thanks alot.. i was working on this for sometime now... but no success yet.. thats why i put it here... ill let u knw about the above answer

Comment: @ShoGumLew: try first using like this: $homepage = file_get_contents('http://localhost/setc.php?userid=123&amp;panelid=1');

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the url. I use file_get_contents like this:

```
file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915659/file-get-content-not-working-throws-an-error');
```

Worked fine for me.